# Better solution for Inserting Data from multipe tables, T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have three tables - `MainTable`, `Country` and `VisaType`.

Table 1 - **MainTable**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| MainTableID | ApplicantName | CountryID | VisaTypeID | Date |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table 2 - **Country**:

```
-----------------------
| CountryID | Country |
-----------------------
|     1     |  Japan  |
|     2     | Georgia |
-----------------------
```

Table 3 - **VisaType**

```
-------------------------
| VisaTypeID | VisaType |
-------------------------
|     1      |    B2    |
|     2      |   H1-B   |
-------------------------
```

I want to get the following result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| MainTableID | ApplicantName | CountryID | VisaTypeID |      Date      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1      |     George    |     2     |     1      | 2018 - 02 - 22 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am doing this so:

```
INSERT INTO MAINTABLE (ApplicantName, CountryID, VisaTypeID, Date)
    SELECT 'George', CountryID, VisaTypeID, '2018-02-22'
    FROM Country, VisaType    
    WHERE Country.Country = 'Georgia'  
      AND VisaType.VisaType = 'B2'
```

**The question is**: what should be better solutions for this task and is it possible to make it with using inner joins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine.  And, as much as I admonish against using commas, you actually are doing a Cartesian product here.  I would phrase this as:

```
INSERT INTO MAINTABLE (ApplicantName, CountryID, VisaTypeID, Date)
    SELECT 'George',c. CountryID, v.VisaTypeID, '2018-02-22'
    FROM Country c CROSS JOIN
         VisaType vt
    WHERE c.Country = 'Georgia' AND vt.VisaType = 'B2';
```

Some people do expression this as a `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO MAINTABLE (ApplicantName, CountryID, VisaTypeID, Date)
    SELECT 'George',c. CountryID, v.VisaTypeID, '2018-02-22'
    FROM Country c CROSS JOIN
         VisaType vt
         ON c.Country = 'Georgia' AND vt.VisaType = 'B2';
```

All three are equivalent, but I would discourage using the version with the comma.

Comment: @Beginner: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.